# Using keyboard.record() in a callback function

Tags: python, callback

So the issue I'm having is with calling keyboard.record() in a function used as a callback. For example, if I run this code:

```
print("start")
num = keyboard.record(until="enter")
print("end")
```

It works fine, printing "start" and then waiting until enter is pressed and then printing "end". It even works if I put it in a function and call it:

```
def hi():
    print("start")
    num = keyboard.record(until="enter")
    print("end")
    
test = hi()
```

But the problem arises when I use it as a callback for keyboard.add_word_listener()

```
def hi():
    print("start")
    num = keyboard.record(until="enter")
    print("end")

keyboard.add_word_listener("hi", callback=hi)
```

Here, if I type "hi" and then put a space, it does print "start," but it does not print "end" when I type something and press enter. What is the reason for keyboard.record() to fail to work in a callback, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am also having a similar issue. My issue happens when using keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+a', my_function) to call the function.