# How to run my Python program when a hotkey is pressed and take user input entered after hotkey?

Tags: python

A simplified example of what I imagine is:
I have some function that takes input and prints it. I want to type something like "abc apple {ENTER}" in an application such as Notepad, and Python upon seeing I typed "abc" will save "apple" to a variable and send it to my function to be printed. I only want things typed after the hotkey "abc" to be sent to the function, and it would stop taking in input after seeing an enter key.

In the past I had used AutoHotKey to get user input after a hotkey is entered but I want to do it with Python.

Is this possible? What module could I use to accomplish this?

Comment: So you want to enter "abc apple " in the console or what?

Comment: I want to be able to type it in another application such as Notepad and Python be listening to the keyboard

Comment: You are looking for something like the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65726049/using-keyboard-record-in-a-callback-function). As you can see, this pattern raises a problem that no one has answered yet. I've seen people recommending using a while loop with `keyboard.read_key()` instead of `keyboard.record()`; however, I've not been successful in making that method work either. For now, this looks like an unsolvable problem in python at least.

Comment: You can check the `keyboard` module [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.read_event). It's not well-documented in my opinion, but you can play around or google individual functions for examples and brainstorm some workarounds. If you find a workaround, provide it as an answer here and link it in the other question I linked to help that person.

Comment: You need a "Windows hook".  You can do this with the `pywinauto` module.